# Installing an Ecobee3 - Wiring Question

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

[image: Living Room]

[image: Garage]

This shows what my wiring looks like in the living room and garage. I had a Honeywell Thermostat that I want to replace with an Ecobee 3, is it possible to use the C terminal for this?

The red wire broke when I popped the Honeywell from the wall. There is also a blue wire that is unused on both ends.

Comment: Can you move the left-hand red wire out of the way in the shot of the furnace board and take a new photo?

Comment: In the second photo (furnace control board), what is the label on the furthest left terminal?

Comment: It is labeled C, forgot to add that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the terminal on the end is `C`, though the label is blocked in the photo.

[image]

If it is marked `C`, then the installation is simple.

1. Connect the unused blue wire to the terminal marked `C` in the furnace/air handler.
2. Connect the other end of the unused blue wire to the `C` terminal on the thermostat.

---

If that is not a `C` terminal. Please post the make and model number of the furnace/air handler, and/or a schematic for the unit.

Comment: It is a C terminal on the end, forgot to mention that. I was guessing that is all I would need to do but wanted to double-check. I'll test it out here. and see how it goes. Thanks